# weka API import

Tags: java, weka, forecasting

I am an inexperienced weka API user and I am having problems with importing `weka.classifiers.TimeSeries.WekaForecaster` and `weka.classifiers.TimeSeries.core.TSLagMaker`. It is like they do not exist, they are not being recognized. My Weka version is `3.7.12`, I am working with Java and my IDE is Eclipse Luna. Did anyone have this same problem or know how to solve this?

Thanks